# Why does git checkout master resets my edits?

Tags: git, commit, git-checkout

Basically, I was working already in the master branch , (I hadn't checked out to another branch) and after doing git add . and git commit, I accidentally ran git checkout master, now when I do git push it says everything is up to date (but ofcourse its not). Quite an odd one.

Comment: What's the question/problem? Checking out the branch you are on won't change anything…

Comment: what are the results when you run `git remote show origin`?

Answer (score 4):

If you're already on master and you do git checkout master nothing will happen, so you must have done something that's not included in your question.

Do gitk --all.  Do you see your commit either on local master or on origin/master?  If not then do git reflog and look for your commit.  Maybe you were in a detached HEAD state so the commit didn't get saved to any branch.  In that case make sure you have master checked out and  git cherry-pick .

Worst case scenario is you thought you committed, but you didn't, and then you thought you checked out master, but you actually checked out the file you edited, thus overwriting your changes before they were saved to git.  If you don't see anything in reflog, probably something like that happened.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i was in master but I just checked it and its deleted all the files i created, but its ok it wasnt that complex so ill do it again, thanks for your responses,

Comment: If you have commited, those changes are not lost. Check git reflog if you want to get them back.